# Make enumerable prototype property enumerate on instance

Tags: javascript

## The problem

I have created an enumerable property on the prototype of a constructor:

```
// Definition of constructor function C is outside of my control
Object.defineProperty(C.prototype, 'foo', {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function() { /* Do something */ },
    set: function(_foo) { /* Do something */ }
}
```

Obviously, this won't show up among the enumerable properties of instances created using that constructor:

```
var c = new C();
Object.keys(c); // Does not include foo
```

I need `foo` to show up as an enumerable property on `c`. I do not have control over the constructor function `C`. Is there any way to achieve this?

## Possibility 1

I have considered turning the getter and setter code into "property generation" code leveraging the fact that `this` will refer to the instance when they are called. So I should be able to do this:

```
function makeFoo(obj) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {
        enumerable: true,
        get: function() { /* Actual getter for foo */ },
        set: function() { /* Actual setter for foo */ }
    });
}
Object.defineProperty(C.prototype, 'foo', {
    get: function() { if (!this.hasOwnProperty('foo') makeFoo(this); },
    set: function(_foo) { 
        if (!this.hasOwnProperty('foo') {
            makeFoo(this); 
            this.foo = _foo;
        }
    }
});
```

This should probably work (I haven't tested it yet), but it seems really hacky. I can't think of anything else, though, so I'd be interested in opinions/observations on edge cases I may not have considered.

## Possibility 2

Is there any way to find out when the constructor was run? Then I could piggyback on that and attach my properties after the constructor has created the instance. Like I said though, I can't change the actual constructor function, and doing the usual [idiom using call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Using_call_to_chain_constructors_for_an_object) won't work because the constructor is used internally to create instances in places outside of my control.

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to hack your code into a foreign lib. What are you trying to achieve with this whole thing?

Comment: Your property is enumerable. If you `for ... in` over the instance it will show up (that's what enumerable means) but `Object.keys()` only returns the own enumerable keys of the object, not the ones that are inherited.

Comment: @Thomas, ok, I wasn't precise enough in my wording. I'll update the question. And yes, it's part of building a model layer based on Angular $resources. They guard against inherited properties.

Comment: @Thomas, from your second comment I now realize possibility #1 is probably my only option. Agree?

Comment: As far as I can tell from your description, this probably won't work either, because the Engine has no reason to `get` your property and therefore trigger `makeFoo()`. It may work if you hack a value that already exists and is used as early as possible after the creation of the instance. But this is really dirty, and I still don't know what the actual problem is, that requires all this, and wether there's no better solution or approach. But that's all just guessing, at the moment.

Comment: Actually, it works, because it's enough if foo is created lazily. Granted, it's ugly as hell, but it does work. Just wish there was a more elegant way.

Comment: Still don't know what problem you're actually solving here. So I can't tell wether there's a better way.

Comment: I am creating a model layer for an Angular app based on Angular's $resource service. When changing certain properties, I need to update an internal data structure and emit an event, which I'm doing in the respective setters.